# Undefined is not an object error in react native authentication flow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm just trying to learn something in react native and I just ran into this error that I cannot solve:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useAuth.getAuthState')

This code comes from an example code that is actually working but I made some modifications.
Can somebody help me?

These are the 2 files:

router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { SplashScreen } from 'expo';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import useLinking from '../navigation/useLinking';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import HeaderLogo from '../components/HeaderLogo';

import BottomTabNavigator from '../navigation/BottomTabNavigator';
import AuthNavigator from '../navigation/AuthNavigator';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

import AuthProvider, { useAuth } from "./provider";

export default function Router(props) {
  //const { navigate } = props.navigation;
  const { getAuthState } = useAuth();
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = React.useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const [initialNavigationState, setInitialNavigationState] = React.useState();
  const containerRef = React.useRef();
  const { getInitialState } = useLinking(containerRef);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
  }, []);

  async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
    try {
      SplashScreen.preventAutoHide();

      // Load our initial navigation state
      setInitialNavigationState(await getInitialState());

      // Load fonts
      await Font.loadAsync({
        ...Ionicons.font,
        'space-mono': require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
      });

      // Authenticate
      //const {user} = await getAuthState();

      //if (user)
        //setIsLoggedIn(true);

    } catch (e) {
      // We might want to provide this error information to an error reporting service
      console.warn(e);
    } finally {
      setLoadingComplete(true);
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }
  }

  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return(
      <AuthProvider>
        <NavigationContainer ref={containerRef} initialState={initialNavigationState}>
        { isLoggedIn ? (

          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
            title: null,
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              borderBottomColor: '#bbb',
              borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              elevation: 0,
              height: 68,
            },
            headerTintColor: '#000',
            headerTitleStyle: {
            },
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerTitle: props => <HeaderLogo /> }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>

        ) : (

          <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigator} />
          </AuthStack.Navigator>

        )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthProvider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

And provider.js

```
import React, {useMemo, useReducer, useContext} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

//IMPORT REDUCER, INITIAL STATE AND ACTION TYPES
import reducer, {initialState, LOGGED_IN, LOGGED_OUT} from "./reducer";

// CONFIG KEYS [Storage Keys]===================================
export const TOKEN_KEY = 'token';
export const USER_KEY = 'user';
export const keys = [TOKEN_KEY, USER_KEY];

// CONTEXT ===================================
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

function AuthProvider(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState || {});

    // Get Auth state
    const getAuthState = async () => {
        try {
            //GET TOKEN && USER
            //let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
            //let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
            //user = JSON.parse(user);

            if (token !== null && user!== null) await handleLogin({token, user});
            //else await handleLogout();

            return {token, user};
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error)
        }
    };

    // Handle Login
    const handleLogin = async (data) => {
        try{
            //STORE DATA
            let {token, user} = data;
            let data_ = [[USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user)], [TOKEN_KEY, token]];
            await AsyncStorage.multiSet(data_);

            //AXIOS AUTHORIZATION HEADER
            axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${data.token}`;

            //DISPATCH TO REDUCER
            dispatch({type: LOGGED_IN, user:data.user});
        }catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    };

    // Handle Logout
    const handleLogout = async () => {
        try{

            //REMOVE DATA
            await AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys);

            //AXIOS AUTHORIZATION HEADER
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];

            //DISPATCH TO REDUCER
            dispatch({type: LOGGED_OUT});
        }catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    };

    //UPDATE USER LOCAL STORAGE DATA AND DISPATCH TO REDUCER
    const updateUser = async (user) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
            dispatch({type: LOGGED_IN, user}); //DISPATCH TO REDUCER
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    };

    const value = useMemo(() => {
        return {state, getAuthState, handleLogin, handleLogout, updateUser};
    }, [state]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
export { AuthContext, useAuth }
export default AuthProvider;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Then undo your modifications until it works again. Don't drop entire code files and expect us to do your debugging for you.